# Row size too large (> 8126)

Tags: php, mysql

Deu-me um erro ao carregar dados do mysql.

> Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or
>   using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current
>   row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Alguém sabe que tipo de erro é este?

Voltou-me a dar o mesmo erro. Mas agora a solução que me deram não funciona. 
Tenho varios campos text, date, LongBlob.

Ocorre depois de executar este codigo:

```
$sqlupdate3 = "Update tb_detalhe_trabalhador SET
   Nome3='$Nome3',Funcao3='$Funcao3',
   MedicaValidade3='$MedicaValidade3',
   MedicaAnexo3='$MedicaAnexo3',
   EPISValidade3='$EPISValidade3',
   ProjectistaNumero3='$ProjectistaNumero3',
   ProjectistaValidade3='$ProjectistaValidade3',
   GasNumero3='$GasNumero3',
   GasValidade3='$GasValidade3',
   RedesNumero3='$RedesNumero3',
   RedesValidade3='$RedesValidade3',
   SoldadorNumero3='$SoldadorNumero3',
   SoldadorValidade3='$SoldadorValidade3',
   MecanicoNumero3='$MecanicoNumero3',
   MecanicoValidade3='$MecanicoValidade3',
   ClasSoldadorNumero3='$ClasSoldadorNumero3', 
   ClasSoldadorValidade3='$ClasSoldadorValidade3'
where id=$id ";

mysql_query($sqlupdate3) or die(mysql_error());
```

A minha Tabela tem muitos dados. 
Tá a ver esse update? Tem mais 10 vezes esse codigo. Dados tipo text, LongBlob, Date

Comment: Pois e agora necessito de ter a BD a funcionar correctamente s: QUal a forma de conseguir corrigir este problema por agora?

Comment: O ponto mais crítico, além do foco o contexto, é que precisa normalizar a base de dados.. Veja a resposta do @Zuul e as demais também. E sobre o foco da sua questão, a própria mensagem de erro do MySQL já sugere correções...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As respostas já existentes endereçam correctamente o problema, mas eu penso que quando falamos em exceder os limites de uma linha na base-de-dados, estamos a lidar com o design da tabela em si.

O erro indica basicamente que a quantidade de dados é demasiado elevada para caber numa linha com a tua configuração actual. Ao invés de alterares toda a configuração que além de trabalhoso vai gerar problemas de performance no futuro, sugiro redesenhar a(s) tabela(s) para dividir a informação numa forma mais eficiente.

---

## Exemplo

A tua estrutura actual indica-me que estás a guardar na tabela "tb_detalhe_trabalhador" todos os dados:

```php
$sqlupdate3 = "
Update tb_detalhe_trabalhador SET
   Nome3 = '$Nome3',
   Funcao3 = '$Funcao3',
   MedicaValidade3 = '$MedicaValidade3',
   MedicaAnexo3 = '$MedicaAnexo3',
   EPISValidade3 = '$EPISValidade3',
   ProjectistaNumero3 = '$ProjectistaNumero3',
   ProjectistaValidade3 = '$ProjectistaValidade3',
   GasNumero3 = '$GasNumero3',
   GasValidade3 = '$GasValidade3',
   RedesNumero3 = '$RedesNumero3',
   RedesValidade3 = '$RedesValidade3',
   SoldadorNumero3 = '$SoldadorNumero3',
   SoldadorValidade3 = '$SoldadorValidade3',
   MecanicoNumero3 = '$MecanicoNumero3',
   MecanicoValidade3 = '$MecanicoValidade3',
   ClasSoldadorNumero3 = '$ClasSoldadorNumero3', 
   ClasSoldadorValidade3 = '$ClasSoldadorValidade3'
where id=$id ";
```

Os dados podem ser organizados (agrupados) em tabelas distintas, contribuindo assim para uma redução dos dados por linha:

#### Tabela tb_detalhe_trabalhador

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_detalhe_trabalhador` (
  `trabalhador_id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID do trabalhador',
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do trabalhador',
  `funcao` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Função do trabalhador',
  PRIMARY KEY (`trabalhador_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Detalhes dos trabalhadores' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Nesta tabela ficam guardados apenas os dados referentes ao trabalhador que são distintos, ou seja, que se relacionam entre si mas não se combinam com outros existentes.

#### Tabela tb_detalhe_trabalhador_medica

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_detalhe_trabalhador_medica` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id interno',
  `trabalhador_id` int(13) NOT NULL COMMENT 'O "trabalhador_id" da tabela "tb_detalhe_trabalhador"',
  `validade` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT 'Data de validade',
  `anexo` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Documento',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Detalhes do trabalhador para médica' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Nesta tabela ficam unicamente guardados os dados referentes a médica do trabalhador.

A relação entre as tabelas é criada pelo campo `trabalhador_id`.

**Nota:**
O esquema indicado vai-se repetindo por cada grupo de dados que tens, ou seja, terias uma tabela para os dados de `Soldador` , de `Redes`, etc...

Desta forma não enfrentas problemas com os limites da linha na tua tabela e ficas com a informação mais "arrumadinha".

---

## Inserção de Dados

Trabalhando com mais que uma tabela para guardar os dados, tens que inserir os mesmos de outra maneira, segue um exemplo:

1. Inserir os dados da tabela principal

   ```php
   $sql = "
   INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador (nome, funcao) 
   VALUES ($Nome3, $Funcao3)";

   mysql_query($sql);

   $idTrabalhador = mysql_insert_id(); /* recolher ID que acabou de ser criado para
                                          utilizar ao inserir nas tabelas secundárias
                                          e assim criar a relação entre elas */
   ```
2. Inserir os dados nas tabelas secundárias

   ```php
   $sql = "
   INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador_medica (id, trabalhador_id, `validade`, `anexo`)
   VALUES ($idTrabalhador, $MedicaValidade3, $MedicaAnexo3)";

   mysql_query($sql);
   ```

---

## Verificações

Para que a inserção seja controlada, podes ir verificando o estado das coisas à medida que a `mysql_query()` vai sendo executada:

```php
/* Preparar Dados
 */
$sqlTrabalhador = "
INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador (nome, funcao) 
VALUES ($Nome3, $Funcao3)";

/* Inserir
 */
if (mysql_query($sqlTrabalhador)) {

  // recolhe ID do trabalhador
  $idTrabalhador = mysql_insert_id();

  /* Preparar Dados
   */
  $sqlTrabalhadorMedica = "
  INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador_medica (id, trabalhador_id, `validade`, `anexo`)
  VALUES ($idTrabalhador, $MedicaValidade3, $MedicaAnexo3)";

  if (mysql_query($sqlTrabalhadorMedica)) {
    // restantes inserções para as outras tabelas continuam aqui...
  }
  else {
    echo "Ocorreu um erro ao inserir os dados para Médica";
  }
}
else {
  echo "Ocorreu um erro ao inserir os detalhes do trabalhador";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Referência**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large

**Referência 2**: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/innodb-compression-usage.html

---

Você pode querer dar uma olhada neste [`artigo`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/) que explica muito sobre tamanhos de linhas MySQL. É importante notar que, mesmo se você usar campos TEXT ou BLOB, o tamanho da linha pode ainda ser menor 8K (limite para InnoDB), porque ele armazena os primeiros 768 bytes de cada linha de campo na página.

A maneira mais simples de corrigir isso é usar o [`formato de arquivo Barracuda`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_barracuda) com InnoDB. Isso basicamente se livra do problema por completo, apenas armazenar o ponteiro de 20 bytes para os dados de texto em vez de armazenar os abetos 768 bytes.

**1** - Adicionando seguinte ao `my.cnf` arquivo com `[mysqld]` seção.

```
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

**2** - **`ALTER`** na tabela para usar `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`.

```
ALTER TABLE nome_tabela
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED 
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

Comment: Não há forma de alterar apenas os 768 bytes?

Comment: Acrescentando mais bytes?

Comment: @user3253195, conheço apenas esta forma. Add mais um link da documentação com uma explicação legal sobre o assunto.

Comment: Obrigado, assim numa forma rapida como posso alterar a minha tabela? Alterar o my.cnf e o 2 não entendi

Comment: Sim exatamente como descrevi. Altere o `my.cnf` e também altere a sua tabela como no segundo passo é descrito.

Comment: e só é necessario isso?

Comment: my.cnf é o my.ini?

Comment: Sim. O Windows usa *.ini para inicializar aplicativos, enquanto linux usa *.cnf ou *.conf, normalmente.

Answer (score 4):

As possíveis respostas para sua dúvida são bastante complexas e técnicas porque elas variam pelo próprio [formato de arquivo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-format.html) InnoDB. Hoje em dia existem dois formatos chamados **Antelope** e **Barracuda**.

O arquivo central de tabelamento (ibdata1) é sempre no formato [Antelope](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_antelope). Se você usar o modo *file-per-table* você pode criar arquivos individuais que podem usar o formato [Barracuda](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_barracuda) simplesmente por setar `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` no arquivo **my.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

Os pontos básicos principais de isso ocorrer são:

- Uma página de 16KB de informações armazenadas em InnoDB deve conter no mínimo duas linhas de informações. Adicionalmente, cada página tem um cabeçalho e um rodapé contendo *checksums*, números de sequências de log e etc. Aqui é onde você obtém seu limite de um bit menor que 8KB por linha.
- Dados de tipos de tamanhos fixos, como INTEGER, DATE, FLOAT e CHAR, são armazenados nesta página de dados primária e acrescidos ao tamanho limite.
- Dados de tipos de tamanhos variáveis, como VARCHAR, TEXT e BLOB, são armazenados nas páginas de sobrecarga, então eles não contam totalmente para o limite total máximo da linha.

No formato **Antelope** até 768 bytes de cada coluna são armazenados na página de dados primária **além** de serem armazenados na página de sobrecarga.

O formato **Barracuda** suporta um [formato dinâmico de linhas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html) o que permite a ele armazenar somente um ponteiro de 20-bytes na página de dados primária.

- Dados de tipos de tamanho variáveis são, também, prefixados por 1 ou mais bytes para codificar seus comprimentos.  E o formato de linhas do InnoDB também possui um array dos *offsets* de campos.  A estrutura interna é mais ou menos documentada [no wiki deles](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_InnoDB).

O formato Barracuda também suporta o [ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-compression.html) para aumentar ainda mais a eficiência para armazenamento de informações de sobrecarga.

Minhas sugestão é na direção de você checar a modelagem do seu banco ou pelo menos dessa tabela pois dificilmente se excede o limite máximo das linhas se tabela estiver bem modeladas.  Esse problema é um forte indício de que você esteja violando a condição dos [grupos de repetição](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups) da Primeira Forma Normal.

Um *workaround* seria proceder com a alteração do **my.cnf** conforme acima e alterar a estrutura da tabela passando a usar o [ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-compression.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tabela
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED 
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8;
```

[Resposta Original](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-format.html) de [Bill Karwin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_antelope) no Database Administrators da Stack Exchange.

Tradução, adaptação e complemento: Bruno Augusto (quem será ele?)

Comment: Uma possivel solução será dividir a tabela actual em 2 ou 3 ?

Comment: Dividir em tantas quantas forem necessárias para normalização. Sem conhecer sua aplicação eu poderia dizer que você precisaria de uma tabela para os dados dos **trabalhadores**, outra para os... dados de validade? (não sei o que isso representa) e uma terceira para relacionar ambas as tabelas.

Comment: mas se criar 16 tabelas para cada trabalhador ja ajudava.. Não consigo é relacionar as mesma

Comment: Uma explicação rápida e grosseira: As tabelas de trabalhadores e de "validade" t~em (ou teriam) um ID primário, certo? Essa terceira tabela teria no mínimo duas colunas, uma para se relacionar com o ID primário de cada tabela. Na hora de selecionar os ados, você faria uma JOIN.

Comment: +1 para a menção à remodelagem. A implementação atual tende a atingir uma limitação física da plataforma. Remodelagem e normalização irão garantir funcionamento, estabilidade e escalabilidade.

Comment: Sem contar uma manutenibilidade muito mais fácil e, dependendo da linguagem servidor sendo utilzada, até mesmo melhor performance.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, o que fiz para resolver este problema foi alterar a tabela assim:

```
Set oRSw = abredb.Execute("ALTER TABLE nome_tabela ENGINE=MyISAM ;")
Set oRSw = nothing
```

Comment: Podes explicar porque de que maneira esta resposta ajuda/resolve o que foi perguntado?

Answer (score 0):

I could update change my engine from MyISAM to InnoDB with this approach.

```
SET SESSION innodb_strict_mode=0;  
ALTER TABLE `tblHostQualityVisit` ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
SET SESSION innodb_strict_mode=1;
```